insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint, key is not present in table
I'm trying to insert an entry into my database with a one-to-one relationship to another entity. I'm using spring data jpa and postgres.
My code looks as follows:
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public abstract class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long botId;

    private String description;

    private boolean hasBeenUsed;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String imageUrl;

    @CreationTimestamp  
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;  

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PollPost extends Post {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PollPostImageTextData pollImageTextData;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PollPostImageTextData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String question;
    private String answerA;
    private String answerB;
    private String correctAnswer;
}

If I now try to create a PollPost as follows:
protected PollPost createPollPost(long botId) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Generating Poll Post...");

        String textData = "{\n  \"question\": \"sample question?\",\n  \"answerA\": \"sample answerA\",\n  \"answerB\": \"samepleAnswerB\",\n  \"correctAnswer\": \"answerB\"\n}";
        String description = "sample desc";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PollPostImageTextData pollImageTextData = new PollPostImageTextData();
        try {
            System.out.println("Generating image text data...");
            pollImageTextData = mapper.readValue(textData, PollPostImageTextData.class);
            System.out.println(pollImageTextData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (pollImageTextData == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Poll Image Text Data must not be null");
        }

        String imageUrl = "test url";
        PollPost post = new PollPost();
        post.setPollImageTextData(pollImageTextData);
        post.setDescription(description);
        post.setHasBeenUsed(false);
        post.setBotId(botId);
        post.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

        System.out.println("Saving PollPost with PollImageTextData ID: " + (pollImageTextData.getId() != null ? pollImageTextData.getId() : "null"));

        pollPostRepository.save(post);
        return post;
    }

I get the error: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: insert or update on table "poll_post" violates foreign key constraint "fk1db3khk0i1jc6mehnod8fy4r" Detail: Key (poll_image_text_data_id)=(852) is not present in table "poll_image_text_data".
I'm not sure why this occurs, since the @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) annotation of the PollImageTextData should create the necessary entry in the database. Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
Before using a MappedSuperclass I created posts very similar like the following and it worked without any problems.
@Entity  
@Getter  
@Setter  
@ToString  
public class Post {  

@Id  
@GeneratedValue    private Long id;  

private long botId;  

private String description;  

private boolean hasBeenUsed;  

@Column(length = 1000)  
private String imageUrl;  

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private ImageTextData imageTextData;  

@CreationTimestamp  // This annotation automates the timestamping when the entity is persisted  
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)  
private LocalDateTime createdAt;  // Field to store the creation timestamp  

}

and
@Entity  
@Getter  
@Setter  
@ToString  
public class ImageTextData {  

@Id  
@GeneratedValue    private Long id;  
private String question;  
private String answerA;  
private String answerB;  
private String correctAnswer;  
}

Post Creation looked like this:
public Post createPost(long botId) throws IOException {  

String textData = "{\n \"question\": \"sample question?\",\n \"answerA\": \"sample answerA\",\n \"answerB\": \"samepleAnswerB\",\n \"correctAnswer\": \"answerB\"\n}";  
String description = "sample desc";  

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
ImageTextData imageTextData = null;  
try {  
    imageTextData = mapper.readValue(textData, ImageTextData.class);  
    System.out.println(imageTextData);  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}  
//String imageUrl = getPostImage(botId);  

Post post = new Post();  
post.setDescription(imageTextData.getQuestion());  
post.setHasBeenUsed(false);  
//post.setImageUrl(imageUrl);  
post.setBotId(botId);  
post.setImageUrl("sample image");  
post.setImageTextData(imageTextData);  

postRepository.save(post);  
return post;  
}

I would really like to know why this way worked, but after using inheritance it no longer created the imageTextData implicitly?

have you checked whether there actually is a record with this key: 852?

@Stultuske Yes I checked that, there is no record with this key. I understand the error message and it occurs correctly, but I do not understand why the PollImageTextData does not get stored as desired. But thanks for the help!

are you sure it doesn't? Yes, you are trying to use cascade, but you are also manually creating the instance that is to be stored. And that one isn't persisted. That might be the problem

@Stultuske Yes I'm very sure, I verified it multiple times. I've edited my Post above with the way I used to create Posts before making it a MappedSuperclass, which worked without any problems. Would appreciate if you could take a look at it and thank you very much again!

Easy, you've never saved pollImageTextData to database, so when you try to save post it looks for a row in PollPostImageTextData table that doesn't exist.
Just create a repository for PollPostImageTextData and save the pollImageTextData before saving post.
protected PollPost createPollPost(long botId) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Generating Poll Post...");

    // create PollPostImageTextData pollImageTextData ...

    // save it
    pollPostImageTextDataRepository.save(pollImageTextData);

    // create PollPost post ...

    pollPostRepository.save(post);
    return post;
}


Thanks a lot for the answer, this makes sense to me. But before I had my PollPost Entity that inherits from Post I only had a Post Entity. With the Post Entity (which wasnt a MappedSuperclass by that time), I created the Post records in the exact same way and there I did not have to create a Repository for the PostImageTextData. I edited my code above and added the "old way". Would appreciate if you could check it out. Thank you very much!

I don't know exactly why, but it might have something to do with persistence context or there might be some problems with JPA and cascade behavior when dealing with inheritance.

using a pollPostImageTextDataRespository caused detached entity errors, but by looking closer at those I was able to figure out the main reason that caused the errors in the first place. Thanks a lot for your help!

The reason why it worked before without inheritance and no longer with inheritance was due to a naming error on my side...
I called the field pollImageTextData but it should have been pollPostImageTextData. This way Hibernate was not able to map things correctly. A really silly mistake, but in case anyone experiences something similar, double check your namings, especially if they are as long and nested as mine.
Thanks a lot to anyone who tried to help!
